# Measure download and upload speed in Browser

Tags: java, javascript, html

I need to measure download and upload speed from my server to browser in the browser.

The main problem is that it must work in ie 8 and firefox 3.6 and I'am not allowed to use flash or an applet.

The server backend is tomcat.

Doing it in html5 and xhr 2 was no problem, but now I got stuck.

I you the download measurement running so far.

But I have no really idea to measure the upload.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: "I got stuck" isn't really enough information for us to help you.  Please tell us *specifically* what you are doing and what problem(s) you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Try this JS code:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

// Call your server here...

var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
alert('Response fetched in ' + time + ' ms');
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/pXnDR/

Since you need to use quite old browsers, I provided here a plain vanilla Javascript solution without the use of any modern libraries like jQuery, ExtJS etc

Comment: I did this for the download. Works. Thank you.

Comment: I got the upload test working, too. I created in iframe with a form an textarea. I filled the textarea with about 10mb text und post it so server. I measured from post start and response arrival. The results are similar to one I got from the html5 version.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be automated, try using built-in Developer tools to measure the response each upload/download takes:

IE 8:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx

Firefox 3.6 (using Firebug):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

These work similarly to the Chrome browser Developer Tools, and can help track response times of live sites

Comment: In the developer tools aren't available in the environ there the test must run.

Comment: What^? I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: The developer tools und firebug aren't activated in the customers environment. They are disabled through user policies.